# How do I parse large amounts of data in XLSX with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I want to process some 48,000 rows to build a dashboard and show some stats based on the data in those rows. One particular field which has a length of 30 characters also has some data in form of substrings. How do I parse all of this data, row by row, to come up with the end result? There are plenty of examples out there, couldn't relate to them just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the "js-xlsx" library in one of my application. The performance is considerably seems to be good.

Here is the github URL.

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: Which funcltions/modules do you suggest for me to use? And for relatively large amount of data, how do you individually parse and store data in each cell? Sorry, I'm new to this @David R

Comment: This library has methods for both reading and writing an. xlsx file. Checkout the detailed documentation given in the Readme file here: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/README.md